# Fit Image & Text in Frame SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two problems with my code.

1. I want to fit my Image into the frame I created. The image format is not the same with that of the frame, I would rather have just part of the image there instead of white borders.
2. The title text I created with the blur background should fit into the bottom of the frame.

```
struct VisualEffectView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var effect: UIVisualEffect?
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UIVisualEffectView { UIVisualEffectView() }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) { uiView.effect = effect }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            ZStack {
            Image("Yosemite")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .overlay(content: {
                    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(VisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .systemMaterialDark)))
                        .frame(minWidth: 350, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 250, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                        .scaledToFit()
                })
                }.padding()
                    .frame(width: 350, height: 400)
                    .background()
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your blur background, but the rest would work like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            Image("image")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 350, height: 400)
                .cornerRadius(30)
            
                .overlay {
                    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                        .padding()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]